# RAID10 array check slow, and slowing

Tags: linux, centos, raid, hard-drive, mdadm

I run a new CentOS 7 machine. Linux runs on 2x SSD setup, and I also have 4x SAS drives setup in software RAID10. The RAID10 array is large, 4x 12TB drives, so 24TB usable.

File system is: ext4

Now I finished copying some files to it, and I'm doing a raid check *(very first one)*.

```
Every 2.0s: cat /proc/mdstat                                                                                                                                                                                         Mon Oct 14 06:28:38 2019

Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath] [faulty]
md127 : active raid10 sdf1[3] sdd1[1] sde1[2] sdc1[0]
      23437503488 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
      [======>..............]  check = 32.6% (7649123136/23437503488) finish=3402.6min speed=77333K/sec
      bitmap: 0/175 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md2 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      20478912 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md3 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sda3[0]
      447318976 blocks [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 3/4 pages [12KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

It started around 250,000K/sec but it keeps getting slower, and it now it's around 75,000K/s

The drives in the RAID10 array are not being use by anything else at the moment.

I already tweaked the speed limit settings.

```
dev.raid.speed_limit_min = 100000

dev.raid.speed_limit_max = 1000000
```

CPU usage is on like 2%, I got tons of RAM free, and the 4 drives in the RAID array are reporting about 25% drive utilization per drive, so they are not being pushed hard by resync.

My question:

1. What can I do to speed this up?
2. And what could be causing it to slow down?

Comment: Been going for 24h now since I posted this. It's done 50%, but speed is slowed down to about 25,000K/s, down from 250,000K/s when it first started. CPU, RAM & IO load is still low.

Comment: Can you post the output of `/sys/block/md127/md/sync_speed`, `sync_speed_min` and `sync_speed_max`? Please also show 60 seconds of `iostat -x -k 1` (using an external pasting service as [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/))

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I've posted the output of all those commands here: https://pastebin.com/MncwCP01 Any help would be appreciated. Raid check is currently on 53%

Comment: Try setting `sync_speed_min` to `50000` and `sync_speed_max` to `200000`. Does it change anything? If not, please post the output of `smartctl --all <dev>` and `dmesg`.

Comment: Changing those settings didn't help unfortunately.  Smartctl output of the 4 raid drives https://pastebin.com/jwYGULYZ Thank you for your help. dmesg output seems a bit large to paste.

Comment: It seems the array has some very brief burst of activity, then it does basically nothing for extended periods of time. Can you post the output of `cat /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_m*`? Do you see any blocked task in `dmesg` or syslog?

Comment: The speed limit settings are correct. Both min and max are set high enough. I've outputted dmesg here: https://pastebin.com/Mb1ZxhxK and the output of "messages" here: https://pastebin.com/eVDrKE9G There are some errors happening it seems, poweron-off stuff also. Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: your `message` file show exactly what I expected: a disk/enclosure continuously aborting commands and resetting. The affected disk seems always to be `sdc`. I'll write an answer to describe what you can/should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `message` file show exactly what I expected: a disk/enclosure continuously aborting commands and resetting. The affected disk seems always to be `sdc`, so it is probably the culprit.

The obvious action to solve the problem is to replace it. However, I would first try to:

- reseat your drive and power/data cables;
- swap `sdc` with another disk (to change SAS cable/power cord) and check if the errors follows the drive or remain bound to the very same  slot/port;
- optionally, read directly from the disk via `dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/null bs=1M iflag=direct` to gain additional debug data.

If you can't, for some reason, replace the drive, you can try forcing bad blocks reallocation by completely rewrite the device via `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1M oflag=direct`. **BIG WARNING: this will completely and irreversibly destroy all data on `sdc`**. Try it *only* if you really can't replace the drive.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I will inform my hosting company.